# MySQL stops after inserting 255 rows

Tags: php, mysql

I got a pretty large DB-Table that I need to split into smaller tables for different reasons.

The handling happens via php close to this example:

```
// Note: It's an example and not working code - the actual function is much larger
function split_db()
{
    $results = "
        SELECT *
        FROM big_table
    ";

    foreach ( $results as $result )
    {
        // Here I split the big_tables contents and ...
        $some_val = $result->SomeVal;
        // ...
        $another_val = $result->AnotherVal;

        // ... here I insert the contents in the different tables
        $sql = "
            INSERT
            INTO first_small_table
            // ...
            VALUES
            // ...
        ";
    }
}
```

**Problem:** The query inserts 255 rows, no matter if I'm in the local environment or on the test server.

**Question:** Why? What am I doing wrong or am I missing something? And how would I avoid this?

*Info about MySQL-Client-Version:*

- *Dev-Server:* 5.0.32,
- *Local Dev-Env.:* 5.1.41

I'm no MySQL-Hero, so **any** help and explanation is appreciated, as Google brought nothing meaningful (to me) up. Thanks!

Comment: When you `SELECT * FROM big_table` does it return all of the rows?

Comment: @Mahdi.Montgomery Yes, it does.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I bet you have your primary key of `unsigned tinyint` type, that has limit of 255 for the maximum value.

So change it to just `int`

```
ALTER TABLE first_small_table MODIFY id INT;
```

Comment: `ID tinyint(15) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT` and `PRIMARY KEY  (ID)`. Could you explain me what's happening?

Comment: @kaiser: `UNSIGNED` `tinyint` can store numbers in interval 0..255. You need to change it to `int`

Comment: @kaiser: I updated my answer with a command to change the type to proper one

Comment: I already upvoted. Could you explain to me (as it's part of the Q) why the heck the `PRIMARY KEY` infulences the max number of rows? Thanks.

Comment: @kaiser: It's not the PRIMARY KEY, it's the type! `UNSIGNED TINYINT` ranges from 0 to 255. Therefore, once you added 255 rows in your table, it cannot insert more row because the primary key cannot be bigger (you can't store the value 256 in a tinyint). Good catch zerkms, +1!

Comment: @kaiser: I repeat for the **3rd time**, not the PK, but `unsigned tinyint` has limitation of maximum allowed numbers. As long as you reached value of 255 - it cannot be incremented anymore, as long as it is 1byte size.

Comment: @zerkms: So my missunderstanding was (for all time so far) that when I create a table and set a `type` for a column than the `type` is the limit for _all_ fields in the DB? I always thought it only affects a single field.

Comment: @kaiser: You said the type of your column is tinyint. A tinyint can only store numbers from 0 to 255. This means your column can only store numbers from 0 to 255. This has nothing to do with any other column!

Comment: @Vincent Savard: "_(...)and set a type for a column than the type is the limit for all fields in the DB(...)_". The Q i was asking was: Is the `type` for all _fields_ in this column, or for _every single field_ (in this specific column)?

Comment: @kaiser: I hate the word field because it has no clear meaning in relational databases. The type means that every value of your column must be of this type. If the type of your column is unsigned tinyint, it means that every value in this column must be of type unsigned tinyint, therefore they must be within 0 and 255.

Comment: @kaiser: type is specific for the particular column

Comment: Zerkms, @Vincent Savard Thanks for your time and the explanation, guys!

Answer (score 5):

I can't say why you're limited to 255 rows, but what I can say is that you can do a single query to add your rows from your big table into your small table with a INSERT INTO ... SELECT query :

```
INSERT INTO first_small_table (col1, col2, col3)
SELECT col1, col2, col3
FROM big_table;
```

If you don't need to use PHP, then by all mean don't use it. It's faster to only use SQL.

Comment: I - sadly - have to write this with php. But +1 anyway :)

Comment: @kaiser: Any particular reason why you have to?

Comment: I'm not the one touching the client server. There's also a chance that I won't be the one developing the next version. Etc. Lot's of reasons...

Comment: You can still launch the query from PHP, you're already doing it. The only difference is that you can write a much more efficient code. Basically, writing a single query is a win-win situation : it's faster and easier to maintain.

Comment: I have to add that I'm doing modifications to single fields. Eg. summing up some. Before that I'm checking if the values exist, then adding prefix/suffix, etc.

Comment: @kaiser: Most likely, if you can do it in PHP, you can do it in SQL. If you need help creating your query, create a new post, I'm sure a lot of people will be able to help you.

Comment: I'll sure come back on your offer. But not tonight. I'm just too tired to get more usefull stuff into my brain :)

Comment: As you offered to help maybe bringing this into a single query, I took the time to sum it up and [here's my Q](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7035039/mysql-sum-up-into-a-single-query-incl-google-maps). Thanks a lot! :)