# MySQL > sum up into a single query (incl. google maps)

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps-api-3

This Q is posted as a follow up to a comment on one of my Qs by @Vincent Savard.

Currently I'm trying (with some success - hitting timeout after 60 sec. for google-maps XML requests) to split data from a (pretty) large table into lots of smaller tables - plus converting/modifying/etc them on the fly. For this task I'm using php close to the following example:

```
// The following happens inside some functions.
// The main table has some "groups" of content.
// fn_a creates the new small tables
"
CREATE TABLE {$small_table_a}
    col_group_a_id int UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    col_group_a_fname tinytext,
    col_group_a_lname tinytext,
    col_group_a_valA tinytext,
    col_group_a_valB tinytext,
    col_group_a_address tinytext,
    col_group_a_lat decimal(9,3),
    col_group_a_lng decimal(9,3),
    PRIMARY KEY  (id)
"
"
CREATE TABLE {$small_table_b}
    col_group_b_id int UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    col_group_b_fname tinytext,
    col_group_b_lname tinytext,
    col_group_b_valA tinytext,
    col_group_b_valB tinytext,
    col_group_b_address tinytext,
    col_group_b_lat decimal(9,3),
    col_group_b_lng decimal(9,3),
    PRIMARY KEY  (id)
"

// fn_b loads the content from the big table, modifies it and saves it row per row into the small tables
$sql = "
SELECT *
FROM {$big_table}
"
foreach ( $sql as $data )
{
    $id = $data->id;

    $group_a_fname = $data->group_a_fname;
    $group_a_lname = $data->group_a_lname;
    $group_a_lname = "{$group_a_fname}, {$group_a_lname}";
    $group_a_valA = $data->group_a_valA ? $data->group_a_valA : '-';
    $group_a_valA = $data->group_a_valB ? $data->group_a_valB : 'none';
    $group_a_valA = $data->group_a_address;

    $group_b_fname = $data->group_b_fname;
    $group_b_lname = $data->group_b_lname;
    $group_b_name = "{$group_b_fname}, {$group_b_lname}";
    $group_b_valA = $data->group_b_valA ? $data->group_b_valA : '/';
    $group_b_valA = $data->group_b_valB ? "€ {$data->group_b_valB}" : null;

    "
    INSERT INTO {$small_table_a} ... VALUES ...
    "
}

// fn_c pulls in data from the small tables, asks the google map API for lat & lng and _should_ update the small table

$sql = "
SELECT *
FROM {$small_table_a}
"
foreach ( $sql as $data )
{
    $output['id'] = $data->id;

    $address = urlencode( $data->address );
    $url = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address={$address}&sensor=false";
    $content = file_get_contents( $url );
    $file_data = new SimpleXMLElement( $content );
    $file_data = $file_data->result ? $file_data->result : null;
    if ( ! $file_data ) 
        continue;
    $location = $file_data->geometry->location;
    $output['lat'] = (string) $location->lat;
    $output['lng'] = (string) $location->lng;
}
foreach ( $output as $data )
{
    "
    UPDATE {$table}
    SET lat=SET lat={$data['lat']}, lng={$data['lng']}
    WHERE id=$data['id']
}
```

**Question:** How could I do this in *one* query? Or how could I reduce DB-queries? And how would I add the lat/lng to the tables without interrupting the query building when my geocoding limit was exceeded for today - I don't want to drop everything just because I've gone over my limit.

Thanks!

*Note: The example was written by hand straight out of my mind. Failures may be in there.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to know what the INSERT INTO query is in you foreach loop, because this is the one that can be summed into one query. Basically, here is the idea:

```
INSERT INTO {$small_table} -- you can specify which columns to fill,
                           -- i.e. INSERT INTO table (col_a, col_b)
    SELECT group_a_fname, group_a_lname, 
           group_a_valA, group_a_valB, 
           group_a_address, group_b_fname, 
           group_b_lname, group_b_valA, group_b_valB -- etc
    FROM {$big_table};
```

Obviously, you'll have to adapt the query to fill your needs. You just need to grasp the idea behind it : you can insert rows with a SELECT query.

The UPDATE query is different because you have to rely on external data (a website). I don't think there is an easy way to do it in one query, but I may be wrong.

Comment: Thanks for coming around :). Problem is that I need to modify these values on the fly. Something like in the first `foreach` statement in the code shown in the Q.

Comment: @kaiser : You can, look at the CONCAT function.

Comment: Afaik this allows me to combine multiple columns, but not altering the values, right?

Comment: @kaiser : Yes, you still can alter values, depending on what you want to do! I don't know what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: In detail: I'm trying to convert a given address string via google geocoding to lat,lng&address and then add it to the DB. I also try to simply combine other values to new strings depending on if all the values are set. If not, I just take part of them and save it into the new table.

Comment: Then no, I don't think it is possible to do it with your RDBMS (and thus, in one query). You might want to check stored procedures though. Usually, you can do any altering if you only use data stored in your database.

Comment: After reading briefly into "stored procedures", I can only say "Thanks a lot". I haven't know anything about it before. So: Marked as solution.